# Missing X and Y axis when plotting using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I having some issue replicating the example code for scatter plots in python. The code I am trying to replicate:

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

plt.subplot(321)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker=">")

plt.subplot(322)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker=(5, 0))

verts = list(zip([-1., 1., 1., -1.], [-1., -1., 1., -1.]))
plt.subplot(323)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker=(verts, 0))
# equivalent:
#plt.scatter(x,y,s=80, c=z, marker=None, verts=verts)

plt.subplot(324)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker=(5, 1))

plt.subplot(325)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker='+')

plt.subplot(326)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker=(5, 2))

plt.show()
```

What I am expecting:
[image]

But this is what I am getting:
[image]

I can get the background to white by:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

But I can not get to display X and Y axis. I have tried many solutions from other stackoverflow posts but none of them seems to be working.

Could someone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HYRY's solution.

Some more references about style sheets in matplotlib for beginners like me:

1. [Customizing plots with style sheets](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html)

   - Defining your own style
   - Composing styles
   - Temporary styling
2. [Matplotlib Style Gallery](https://tonysyu.github.io/raw_content/matplotlib-style-gallery/gallery.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using ggplot style. You can change the default style:

```
pl.style.use("ggplot")
pl.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = "#777777"
pl.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = '#FFFFFF'
```

Here is the result:

[image]